# Django CreateView request pass

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using [django-better-form](https://github.com/fusionbox/django-betterforms). A great tool for multi form support. One problem is I want to pass `request` to the modelform. Using `kwargs.pop("request")` I faced `KeyError`. How to fix this

My forms.py:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class BarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = '__all__'


class FooBarMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'foo': FooForm,
        'bar': BarForm,
    }
```

`views.py`

```
class PassRequestToFormViewMixin:
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(PassRequestToFormViewMixin, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs

class FooCreateView(PassRequestToFormViewMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = FooBarMultiForm
    template_name = 'template.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('list')
```

Comment: You need to show your code and the error.

Comment: bro, check now Updated ques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the request to form via [get_forms_kwargs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs):

```
class SomeView(FormView):

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(SomeView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['request'] = self.request
        return kwargs
```

and catch it in the form:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)        

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'


class BarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.request = kwargs.pop("request")  # Need to pop here as well, even if you don't need it
       super(BarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = '__all__'


class FooBarMultiForm(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'foo': FooForm,
        'bar': BarForm,
    }

    def get_form_args_kwargs(self, key, args, kwargs):
        fargs, fkwargs = super(FooBarMultiForm, self).get_form_args_kwargs(key, args, kwargs)  # call super
        fkwargs.update({'request': kwargs.get('request')})  # update form kwargs with request
        return fargs, fkwargs
```