# Django add filter to ForeignKey drop-down

Tags: python, django

In my Django application I have Items and Locations. Each Item could be linked to a Location. On the Item view, I want that the user can only select Locations he owns.

Given the following models:

```
from django.conf import settings
from rules.contrib.models import RulesModel

# Create your models here.

class Location(RulesModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Item(RulesModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        Location, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I specify a filter to restrict the Locations available in the view?

```
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

# Create your views here.
from .models import Item

class ItemCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Item
    fields = [
        "name",
        "description",
        "location",
        "owner",
    ]
    success_url = reverse_lazy("item:item-list")

    def get_initial(self):
        return {"owner": self.request.user.id}
```

I've tried to add `def __init__()` to the view and specifying [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) in the model, both without success. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify [`form_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) in your create view.

```py
from .forms import ItemCreateForm

class ItemCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Item
    form_class = ItemCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("item:item-list")

    def get_initial(self):
        return {"owner": self.request.user.id}
```

In `forms.py` filter the field in `__init__`:

```py
from django import forms

from .models import Location, Item

class ItemCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = [
            "name",
            "description",
            "location",
            "owner",
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['location'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Location.objects.filter(), # <- Here goes your filters
        )
```

For passing `request.user` in case you are trying to filter `owner=user`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572973/django-createview-request-pass).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! In the view I had to remove the fields, because you shouldn't specify fields and form_class at the same time.

Comment: Do you know why it's not possible to specify the queryset in the ItemCreateView itself?

Comment: @GianLucaDecurtins Thanks for you're notice. Well logically you are trying to edit the queryset of a field, which is exactly what form classes are built for. Please accept my answer if it was helpful.